# Python API to call Docker container endpoint

Tags: python, docker, azure-language-understanding

I am new to python and Docker. I have a LUIS endpoint on Azure and I have containerized it on docker on my localhost listening to port 5000. Now I need to create a python web api, that will call this (LUIS container) docker endpoint.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Looks like you an create containers with. https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html

You already have an endpoint hosted in a Docker container? Now you need a python script that calls that endpoint? Then I think you need the requests container. Best is to put your API credentials in environment variables which you can get with: os.environ: docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

Comment: Thanks for the links. But here they are pulling a docker image and running the container. I have an endpoint already doing that, where can i configure just the url to endpoint in python api?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question. You already have an endpoint hosted in a Docker container? Now you need a python script that calls that endpoint? Then I think you need the requests container. 

Best is to put your API credentials in environment variables which you can get with: os.environ: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.environ

Comment: yes I did try with requests and looks like it is working.

Comment: Thanks! Can you mark my answer as the right one?